# html upload image from specific path on OSX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails, groovy

I'm using OSX 10.9, grails 2.4.0

the location where I save image is `/Users/opt/`

On `config`, I set

```
logoPath {
    url = "/Users/opt/"
}
```

On html:

```
<%
def url = grailsApplication.config.logoPath.url
def logo = '1.png'
def imagePath = url + logo
%>
<img src="${imagePath}"/>
```

It cannot load image and I open firebug, it shows directory: `"/Users/opt/1.png"` and message: Failed to load the given URL
(note that 1.png is stored on opt directory)

However, I change the path to `<img src="../images/1.png"/>`, it works.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First OSx is similar to Linux... please check the permission on that folder. Most of the time you **can not copy or past** even a folder unless u used a command line.

> sudo cp -a source /opt/

for that matter see the permission on that folder ,or u can change its permission using

> sudo chown -R yourusername /opt

to list the permission and files status

> ls -alh

But , i suggest you do upload or download images in `/tmp/`  folder or on your project folder under `web-inf` and `/temp /`

Comment: Thanks bro, does it need permission when run on Windows?

Comment: it depends on which folder u want to put , good news is windows is not restricted as Linux or Mac so certain that u ca put it even in system32/ cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/opt` is a path on your local file system. Your browser isn't accessing your file system, it's talking to your web server. Web server paths aren't the same as paths on your file system. If you want to server files out of `/Users/opt` (or anywhere else outside of the server's root folder) then you need to use some kind of proxy, where the server reads the file for you, and serves it up under an alternate accessible URL.